# How do you manually add a space to an input field in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I've been having a hell of a time with the datepicker from the angular bootstrap.
Essentially, it functions as it should, where the new chosen date is displayed in the input field, but it doesn't update the date directive unless there is a manual change to the field (i.e. you add a space to the end of the text).

I've tried everything, and the only thing I can think of is to simulate that space character being added when the form is submitted.

So my question is:
When the submit button is clicked, how do I add that space at the end?

Note: I cannot use jQuery.

Comment: _"I cannot use jQuery."_ Then why did you add that tag?

Comment: Also, I think you'd better ask _"How do I trigger the change event on the datepicker field?"_

Comment: `form.onsubmit = function() { changeDate(); }` where `changeDate` triggers a change on the field.

Comment: @Cerbrus doh! I didn't mean to add that tag.

Comment: @RUJordan I definitely should have phrased the question better. I know how to trigger that change, tying the submit to a function, but I'm not sure how to implement the change within the function (how to simulate the keystroke)